# How do I smoothly transition vinyl plank to tile?

Tags: tile

I’ve read you can use schlutter or flexible caulk which is better

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Sounds like you have two options already. Please revise to tell us more about your project (with photos, if possible), and state the specific problem you're facing.

Comment: All caulk is flexible (at least for the first 5, 10, 15 years, depending on the type) before it starts to degrade, harden and flake out. Do you have a specific "flexible" caulk in mind? What is "schlutter"? Is that a brand name for something? Please feel free to [edit] your post to include more info! Also, take the [tour] and read through the [help] (especially the section on asking questions) so you can learn what to expect, and find out how to help us best help you.

Answer (score 1):

You really have two general options for a "seamless" transition from tile to plank.

1. Basic "L" trim - pictured below.   You will need to install this about 1/8" from each and caulk in between.   It should be installed slightly LOWER than the height of the planks and tile - 1/16", 1/8" be OK.   Your two floors must be pretty much exactly the same height or the "L" trim method will cause foot scrapes.

[image]

2. Bullnose trim - my general suggestion for most as it is more forgiving for slight height misalignments.   Your planks will go into the bullnose and the tiles will be about 1/8-1/16" with a caulked gap.

[image]

Comment: I assume the question is about the floating type of interlocking vinyl planks, these usually require something like a 1/4" expansion gap all around, which would need to be accounted for at this transition as well.

Comment: @PhilippNagel - that is why I gave two options.   Also you don't need 1/4" for pure vinyl.  But "vinyl planks" has a variety of meanings these days.